# find and replace symbol using vbs

Tags: checkbox, vbscript, ms-word, symbols

I am working a 1XXX words documents, I want to use vbs to changing the status of checkbox faster but I can't found any work solution, after that, i wonder if find and replace can solve my issue, so i wrote some code for this

```
Const wdReplaceAll  = 2

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\checkbox.doc")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objSelection.Find.Text = "@1"
objSelection.Find.Forward = TRUE
objSelection.Find.MatchWholeWord = TRUE

objSelection.Find.Replacement.Text = objSelection.InsertSymbol 253, "Wingdings"
objSelection.Find.Execute ,,,,,,,,,,wdReplaceAll
```

But, it can't work, and always show the error on the objSelection.InsertSymbol 253...

Comment: what do you mean by **'changing the status of checkbox'**? have you tried looping through `checkboxes object`?

Comment: How can i use checkboxes object by using vbs? Can you advice?

Comment: CheckBox Object (Word): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839720.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `InsertSymbol` in an assignment like that. Either replace the search text with an appropriate character formatted as "Wingdings":

```
With objSelection.Find
  .Text = "@1"
  .Replacement.Text = ChrW(61693)
  .Replacement.Font.Name = "Wingdings"
  ...
End With

objSelection.Find.Execute ,,,,,,,,,,wdReplaceAll
```

or just `Find` the search text and then use `InsertSymbol` on the selection:

```
objSelection.Find.Text = "@1"
objSelection.Find.Execute

objSelection.InsertSymbol 253, "Wingdings"
```

Comment: Many thx your ans, btw, as your execute, do i need to change wdreplaceall variable to 1 ?

Comment: If you did that, the name of the constant would be misleading. Better create a new constant `Const wdReplaceOne = 1` and use that instead.

Comment: Ok, it works. However, how can i modify the status (tick or untick) of checkbox when i use vbs? Because i am not sure our boss would accept this solution ot mot

Comment: How is that related to your question?